# How to highlight all instances of a cell value in a column based on another cell in same row?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am trying to use either CONDITIONAL FORMATTING or VBA to achieve the following.

Let's assume columns A and B
Column A contains a list of locations and are duplicated many times, eg. the location "ANYWHERE" could be in 20 different rows (but in the same column).
Column B contains a Vlookup code that results in a numerical value (including 0) or are blank.

I want IF column B contains a value that is NOT 0 to highlight ALL INSTANCES of the same location in column A (even if the value is blank or 0 in column B).

So if on row 300, there is a location 'ANYWHERE' and column B (for that row) has a value of '10' then highlight EVERY instance of the word "ANYWHERE" in column A (below and above).

I got halfway there with conditional formatting to highlight the value in column A for any value that is not blank or higher than 0 in column B, but I do not know how to highlight all instances of that value in column A.

Also, if in row 100, 'ANYWHERE' has a value of '20' in column B (and thus all instances of "ANYWHERE" get highlighted, and then in row 200 'ANYWHERE' has no value in column B, that instance of 'ANYWHERE' should NOT get UN-highlighted

The values in the first column should be highlighted based on the value in the last column.
In this case, everything with NM-5F-0335 should be highlighted
[image]

Comment: is it possible that column B could have multiple instances greater than 0 that are associated with multiple words in column A? Like B2 = 10 and A2 = "Hello" AND B3 = 5 and A3 = "BYE"

Comment: Hi Scott. YES. this is very possible. it is also possible that B4 = 20 and A4 is "HELLO" and B5 = 15 and A5 = "BYE"

Comment: So, everything would be highlighted the same color, even if the words are different? 2,3,...10 different words?

Comment: yes...they can all be highlighted in the same color. the thing is, the worksheet has 20K rows. Column A has a value for EACH row out of which about 500 are UNIQUE, but column B has a values in only about 60% of the rows and many of them are 0. I actlually only need to review the rows that (anywhere in the sheet) have a value > 0 in column B and sorting by column A to do that is not an option

Comment: example:

G2-15784 0
NM-5F-0335 0
NM-5F-0335 72
NM-5F-0335 (blank)
NM-5F-0335 (blank)
NM-5F-0335 (blank)
F3-16462         (blank)
NM-5F-0335 72
NM-5F-0335 0
NM-5F-0335 0
F3-16462         (blank)
NM-2F-34192 (blank)

in this case, all instances of NM-5F-0335 need to be highlighted
(I do not know how to get them on different rows to be able to post it clearly)

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62519970/edit) your post with your sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the formula:  `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$12,$A1,$B$1:$B$12,"<>0")>0`

Screenshot for example:

[image]

Comment: this formula should be entered in the conditional formatting section?

Comment: i changed the <>0 to >0 and I find that works better, because if I use <>0 then I even get results where column b is blank. THANKS SO MUCH for your help! got it working!!!